# HTML - How to centering img and text inside div while using float left?

Tags: html, css

I've an image and text in one div parent,

I need to move the image and text to center,

but to let text beside img, I need to use `float: left`

here's the example code:

```css
.boxtitlestillneedHeader {
    background-color:#ff00 ; margin-bottom:15px;
}
.boxtitlestillneed {
    color:#000000; font-size:26px; margin-bottom:1px; font-weight: bold;
}
.smal{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.larg{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: red;
}
.inn{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left boxtitlestillneedHeader" id="status">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 boxtitlestillneed">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/50/50268.png" class="img-responsive" style="float: left; margin-left: 25%;">
   <span class="need smal inn">you still need</span><br>
   <span class="curr larg site-font-bold">IDR</span>
   <span id="resultMoney" class="larg site-font-bold">2,1</span><br>
   <span id="lifep4c2" class="smal">foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

there's a way to make image and text center without using `margin-left: n%`?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey1Lp7a5/1/)

Comment: foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo bar.

Comment: the image need to be on the left of the text, or it will be each element on a single 'line'?

Comment: @CalvinNunes the image need to be on left of the text sir, that's why i'm using `float: left`

Answer (score 0):

You can center align text with text align center.

```
.smal{
font-size: 20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

This should center the image.  Apply this to the container holding the image. hope it helps.

```
.boxtitlestillneedHeader {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: i need an image and text to center, not only the text